# jQuery: How to make keyboard Event do the same on click event together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make click event and arrow right make the same event

So instead of this repeated code

```
$('#foo').on('click',function() {
    //do something
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    //do the same thing above
   }
});
```

How should i do it?

Thank You :)

Comment: assign them both to the same function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make them both trigger the same function.

```
$('#foo').on('click', CoolFunction);

$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    CoolFunction();
   }
});

function CoolFunction() {
  //same thing
}
```

Comment: +1 since it is working, but you are losing the `this` reference, so i would use `trigger()`

Answer (score 3):

Have both call the same function, or alternatively in keydown you could do

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use built in javascript so both have the same context. Don't use trigger, it has side effects.

```
$('#foo').on('click', commonFn);

$(document).keydown(function(){
   if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    commonFn.apply(this,arguments);
   }
});

function commonFn() {
  //same thing
}
```